# use jQuery.each() method to show hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I run a loop and create filters, which I pack in categories (packed in `<ul>`). These filters can be activated with checkboxes (packed in `<li>` within the `<ul>`). I can have 2 or 5 category filters, so 2 or 5 `<ul>` with multiple `<li>` inside each. With css all `<li>` checkboxes above 3 are hidden at start, and I use a "show more" element (in `<span>`) that is located just before `</ul>`.
As it's a loop, all `<ul>` elements use the same id="filterlist" and class="sidebar-ul". Also all the `<li>` checkboxes have the same class="sidebarfilters".
I have a JQuery each function, and on click on one of the `<span>` I only want to show the hidden `<li>` elements, that are placed within the `<ul>` element, in which also the clicked span is located.
At the moment, if I click on one of the "show more" spans, all `<li>` checkboxes of all `<ul>` are shown.
Is there a way (maybe with "$(this)") somehow to show only the correct `<li>`, even though classes are the same?
Also, I want to hide the "show more" span if all `<li>` elements are shown, this is not working as well. The `<span>` stays visible after all checkboxes are shown. Any input would be very much appreciated. My simplified code, CSS and JQuery are:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
  <ul  id="filterlist" class="sidebar-ul">
        {% if current_tags contains tag %} 
             <li class="sidebarfilters">
                 <input  class="filter_checkbox" id="checked" type="checkbox" checked onClick="">         
            </li>     
       <span class="showmorefilters">mehr...</span></ul>
  </ul> 
{% endfor %}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".showmorefilters").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('#filterlist li:hidden').show();
      if ($('#filterlist li').length == $('#filterlist li:visible').length) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebarfilters:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(".showmorefilters").each(function(){` is not needed, `$(".showmorefilters").click(function(){` will suffice

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your question is hard to follow. Explain what's wrong and what's expected.

Comment: Can you add your HTML? It's hard to tell what you're trying to do from the description. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I've created the stack snippet for you. Now you just have to add the HTML to it.

Comment: You state, "*all `<ul>` elements use the same `id="filterlist"`*." Elements must have a unique ID.

Comment: Sorry if I was not cler enough, I posted a simplified code, hope that helps. I try with stack snippet, never did that... I create multiple <ul> elements in a loop, this is why they all have the same id="filterlist"

Comment: @Simonski your example has many HTML issues. You must have Unique ID and `<span>` should not be a child of `<ul>`. Please address the Syntax errors in your HTML output and then update your post with a proper example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like content is being created dynamically. Would advise using `.on()` versus `.click()`. Have to make a lot of assumptions without proper example.

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {
  $("ul[id^='filterlist']").on("click", ".showmorefilters", function(e) {
    var fl = $(this).parent();
    fl.find("li:hidden").show();
    if ($('li', fl).length == $('li:visible', fl).length) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

This will bind a Click event to all `.showmorefilters` elements and perform a callback that is relative to that target.

Comment: Thank you so much @Twisty! And also thanks to the others! I learned a lot in just 15 minutes, I changed span to li as a child of ul. Also, I understood not to give id's in loops, so I changed it to classes. You are great! Thanks from a beginner!!!